# How to set url rewriting in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a redirect script that redirects with this url

> http://my-domain.com/URL.php?url=http://www.google.com

I want to rewrite the url as

> http://my-domain.com/?url=http://www.google.com

or

> http://my-domain.com/?http://www.google.com

I know this can be done with .htaccess so i tried some codes myself. I created a .htaccess file in my web directory and i put some code eg:

```
# Prevent Apache from serving .ht* files:
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^embed/([^\.]+)\.php$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule URL.php /
```

But still it's not working, What's i'm doing wrong here

Comment: I don't think this needs to be tagged with `php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ /URL.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Example: http://yoursite.com/url/http://www.google.com

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^go/(.*)$ /URL.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Example: http://yoursite.com/go/http://www.google.com

It would be better to use it this way.

Comment: I forgot to add the Get parameter. I hope it works. Now you can try.

Comment: and RewriteBase added.

Comment: it works when i use **http://www.yoursite.co/url/?url=http://www.google.com** but script is not working i mean it's not redirecting, when i remove the htaccess code it's working fine...

Comment: I told you I forgot to add the parameters. Have you tried the codes I recently edited? /URL.php?url=$1

Comment: Yeah i know you edited that's why i replied again... script only works when i don't add that .htaccess code but after adding the code it's just not working

Comment: I'm glad you did it.